# How to create an new JSON object with two JSON obj1, JSON ob2 and update an new object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Having two objects key is same and wanted to map to a new object with same key append with `_old` and `_new`. below are the sample objects and the expected result is below. experts, please help :)

```js
oldobj = [
    {
        AddressLine1: "ABC Old",
        AddressLine2: "DEF Old",
        AddressLine3: "GHI Old"
    }
];

newobj = [
    { 
        AddressLine1 : "ABC New",
        AddressLine2 : "DEF New",
        AddressLine3 : "GHI New"
    }
];
```

Below obj has new and old obj, key is same with `_new` & `_old`. Wanted to map the value that .. `_new` with `objnew`(refer the object above) and `_old` value with `objold`(refer the object above)

```js
mixobj=[
    {
        AddressLine1_new : "string",
        AddressLine1_old : "string",
        AddressLine2_new : "string",
        AddressLine2_old : "string",
        AddressLine3_new : "string",
        AddressLine3_old : "string"
    }
]
```

Result to be expected is

```js
mixobj=[
{
AddressLine1_new : "ABC New",
AddressLine1_old : "ABC Old",
AddressLine2_new : "DEF New",
AddressLine2_old : "DEF Old",
AddressLine3_new : "GHI New",
AddressLine3_old : "GHI Old"
}
]
```

Comment: next time format your code with backticks ` and code fences ```

Comment: also show what you have attempted so far